# Specify a private message to have limited answers discord.js

Tags: javascript, async-await, discord

I have a bot asking a question to a user via private message. I would simply like the bot to only accept certain words as answers.

For example, asking a user which gender they are. I would like the options to be "Male", "Female" and "Other". If the bot receives something other than those answers, I would also like it to say "Please enter "Male", "Female" or "Other". I have tried a couple different things that don't seem to work. The code works, outside of the line I am messing with, but will accept "cat", for example, as a gender, so I obviously want it to only accept a few answers. Not sure if the if statement to specify this would work. I know how that works by itself, but in combo with await, I am confused...

Here's the code for what I last tried, with no avail (not to mention it gives a syntax error/unexpected token due to the line I was messing with)

```html
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
message.author.send(`THIRD QUESTION, **What is the gender of your Brawler or Character?** Please enter "Male", "Female" or "Other".`)
  .then((newmsg) => { //Now newmsg is the message you send to the bot
    newmsg.channel.awaitMessages(response => response.content.includes("Male", "Female", "Other") {
      max: 1,
      time: 300000,
      errors: ['time'],
    }).then((collected) => {
      newmsg.channel.send(`Your brawler's gender is: **${collected.first().content}**

      If you are okay with this gender, type !profilerace to continue the profile creation process!

      If you would like to edit your gender, please type !profilegender`)
        con.query(`UPDATE profile SET gender = '${collected.first().content}' WHERE id = ${message.author.id}`);
        console.log("1 record updated!")
    }).catch(() => {
      newmsg.channel.send('Please submit an age for your character. To restart Profile creation, please type "!profilecreate" command in Profile Creation channel on the server.');
    });
      //con.query(sql, console.log);
      //if (err) throw err;
      //console.log("1 record inserted!")
  });
}
```

EDIT: After getting some help in the comments below, I have resulted in something like this. I keep getting syntax errors though. I feel like I have no idea what I'm doing here. lmao

```html
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
message.author.send(`THIRD QUESTION, **What is the gender of your Brawler or Character?** Please enter "Male", "Female" or "Other".`)
  .then((newmsg) => { //Now newmsg is the message you send to the bot
      newmsg.channel.awaitMessages(response => response.content, {
        max: 1,
        time: 300000,
        errors: ['time'],
      })
    .then((collected) => {
        if (response.content === "Male" || response.content === "Female"|| response.content === "Other") {
          return
        newmsg.channel.send(`Your brawler's gender is: **${collected.first().content}**

        If you are okay with this gender, type !profilerace to continue the profile creation process!

        If you would like to edit your gender, please type !profilegender`)
          con.query(`UPDATE profile SET gender = '${collected.first().content}' WHERE id = ${message.author.id}`);
          console.log("1 record updated!")}
        } else {
             newmsg.channel.send("Please submit 'Male', 'Female' or 'Other'. Type !profilegender to restart the choice of gender.")
          }
    }).catch(() => {
      newmsg.channel.send('Please submit an age for your character. To restart Profile creation, please type "!profilecreate" command in Profile Creation channel on the server.');
    });
  });
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're not even using `await` anywhere?

Comment: I am using "await". 4th line.  "newmsg.channel.awaitMessages"

Comment: No, that's just a method called `.awaitMessages`. It's not the `await` keyword that would replace promise `then` calls.

Comment: Oh, right. I see. Then no, I'm not using that right now. I have 4 other questions that I have copied the coding of. The questions work, I just need to know how to put in a filter or way to require a reply of "Male", "Female" or "Other" from the user. Otherwise, it returns a "Please enter 'Male', 'Female' or 'Other'." Reply and await the correct reply again. Apologize on my ineptitude with this. Coding is still a little foreign to me right now.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure exactly what you mean but I would create an ArrayList and check if the content of the message matches with one of the values in the ArrayList as shown below:

```js
const genders = ["male", "female", "other"];

if (genders.indexOf(response.content) > -1) {
    // code if person chose one of the three options.
} else {
    // code here if person did not choose one of the three options and put something else.
}
```

Comment: I saw this as a possible fix, but I wasn't sure how to inject it into my existing code, so I figured I'd ask for some help. I know the constant goes at the top with the rest of them, but as for the if and else, I can put in the .then((collected) section? I am fairly new to coding so stuff a little more complicated like this is a little foreign to me.

Comment: It's okay, I am still a nub at JS (xD). Yeah, put it inside the first .then(). It should be the first thing you do check before moving on to the SQL stuff. Also, to be honest, your messages are cluttering your code, you should maybe separate them into a separate file.

Comment: I messed around with a mix of your idea and something else and I don't know what I am missing or doing wrong. I am getting syntax errors after dozens of attempts at making this work. I added the code I updated to, after your advice, to the OP. I am not sure if what I am doing is even close. XD Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: I would, but I can't seem to find a place on your profile to message you at. I might be missing it though.

Comment: Got'cha. Sent a friend request.